# C# Cosmos Can't Print float variable

Tags: c#, cosmos

I am building a simple OS in C#, using Cosmos.
For some reason I get an error when I try to use my float variable. I know it looks weird, but I really get an error.

```
float a = 1.12f;
Console.WriteLine(a); // gives me errors.
```

The error says :

```
CPU Exception x06
Last known address: 0x0206C600
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: Why this is marked as C# ?

Comment: Because I am using C# in Cosmos

Comment: Cosmos is an operating system "construction kit", built from the ground up around the IL2CPU compiler in C# and our home-brewed language called X#. This is what is written in their git hub page. So probably you are not using C#, you are using X#.

Comment: Also beware that floating point in kernel space is a no-no.

Comment: @PaulStelian why is it no-no?

Comment: Well, it is alright if you ALWAYS save the floating point registers on context switches. But the common optimization of only switching those registers when actually needed forbids the usage of the FPU in kernel space.